Move BasicTextField cursor to specific word in jetpack compose
I have a BasicTextField in Jetpack compose. when I type a word a list of suggested words shows. when I select each site I need to replace the selected word with an uncompleted word. My problem is related to the cursor position. if I write a word with two chars and click on a word with four chars, the cursor stays after char number two and doesn't move to the last char of the new word. how can I handle this?
Note: If it can help to answer, I convert the TextField words to a list of strings and keep the last edited list item in UiState
My TextField Component:

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DescriptionTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    hint: String,
    hintStyle: TextStyle = Typography.Regular22,
    textStyle: TextStyle = Typography.Regular22,
    hashtagMentionWordStyle: TextStyle = textStyle,
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    caption: List<ActionableText>?,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() },
) {
    val textFieldValueState by remember(value) {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextFieldValue(
                text = value
            )
        )
    }
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 48.dp)
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .background(color = Color.Transparent)
    ) {
        if (textFieldValueState.text.isEmpty()) {
            Text(
                text = hint,
                style = hintStyle,
                color = white,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart)
            )
        } else {
            val annotatedString = findHashtagAndMention(caption, hashtagMentionWordStyle)
            Text(
                text = annotatedString,
                style = textStyle,
                color = white,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart)
            )
        }

        BasicTextField(
            value = value,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            textStyle = textStyle.copy(color = Color.Transparent),
            cursorBrush = SolidColor(green),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.Transparent)
                .padding(0.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterStart)

        )

    }
}

@Composable
private fun findHashtagAndMention(
    displayedCaption: List<ActionableText>?,
    hashtagMentionWordStyle: TextStyle
): AnnotatedString {
    val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
        displayedCaption?.forEachIndexed { index, part ->
            if (part.type == ActionableTextType.TAG || part.type == ActionableTextType.PERSON) {
                withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = hashtagMentionWordStyle.color)) {
                    append(part.value)
                }
            } else {
                append(part.value)
            }
            if (index != displayedCaption.size - 1) {
                append(" ")
            }
        }
    }
    return annotatedString
}

and Usage:
  DescriptionTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp))
                        .heightIn(max = 200.dp),
                    hint = stringResource(id = R.string.core_ui_say_some_thing),
                    value = uiState.caption?.list?.joinToString(separator = " ") {
                        it.value
                    } ?: "",
                    hashtagMentionWordStyle = textStyle.copy(color = green),
                    caption = uiState.caption?.list,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onIntent(EnterPostDescriptionIntent.OnCaptionChange(it))
                    },
                )


This question is similar to: How to change text field cursor position in jetpack compose. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I believe what you're trying to do, is some kind of auto-complete functionality, i.e. type something, see a list of suggestions, and then tap a certain suggestion, which gets replaced in the text field, right?
This involves updating the text field async, and there is an official article/recommendation on what to do, while updating state async for the TextField, which can be read here
Compose Team's official solution is to use BasicTextField2, from that article
However I have previously tried the suggestion mentioned in this issue tracker here which worked fine for me. This issue may seem unrelated to your case, but it's the same issue trust me, and I was working on the same use case as yours..
See whichever one helps you!

The issue tracker link is not correct

It seems like that, but your issue and that issue are related, trust me

Both links lead to the same article

Updated it, sorry!
